# Is there a command to copy and compile a c file to another directory?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Is there a command to copy and compile a c file to another directory? So if I have Ticker.c in the home directory, I want to copy it and compile it in another directory called Task

Comment: In general available options depend on the tool in use. Maybe you could [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736116/edit) to add info on your compiler? Please don't reply in a comment.

Comment: There's unlikely to be a command that copies and compiles. Typically you'd use `cp` to copy and something like `cc` or `gcc` to compile. String then together as consecutive commands and you've achieved your aim

Comment: `-o anotherdirectory/ticker`

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a script that does what you would like.  I had some luck with the following

```
#!/bin/bash

# creates a command 'ccto' that copies and compiles 
# a file to a directory. In the following, we have
# <file> : the file to be copied and compiled
# <dest> : the destination of the copied file
# <filename> : the name of the compiled file in <dest>

if [ ! -f "$1" ] || [ ! -d "$2" ] || [ -z "$3" ]
then
    echo "Usage: ccto <file> <dest> <filename>"
    exit 1
fi

gcc "$1" -o "$2/$3"
```

Naming the file `ccto` (**C**opy and **C**ompile **TO**), and changing its permissions to be executable.  As a final step, add this file to some directory in the `$PATH` variable (Or better yet, add it to `~/.bin`, and edit your `.bashrc` file to ensure that this directory is in the `$PATH`, so that this script can be run regardless of the current working directory without having to remember the path of the original file).

This script that I have written is not perfect, as it does not check that the file passed to it is a file that can even be compiled. But it'll do.

Answer (score 0):

You could compile the file in the current directory and then use `install` to copy it into the target directory.

`install` has many options like setting permissions and owner and group, creating a backup file if the file already exists in the target directory etc. It does it all in one go.

For example, running a command like

```
install -b -o alice -m 0700 Ticker.o /target/directory/MyTicker
```

will:

- copy file `Ticker.o` to `/target/directory/MyTicker`,
- **-b**: create a backup file `MyTicker.old` in case `MyTicker` already exists,
- **-o alice**: change the owner to `alice`, and
- **-m 0700**: change permissions to `0700`.